# Extension of MMP from the central fiber to some neighborhood

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, deformation-theory

I was reading Professor Kollár's paper deformation of varieties of general type (here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.10986 )

---

There is a theorem about the extension of MMP step when the central fiber has canonical singularity and it's projective.

The theorem is stated as follows:

> **Theorem 2.** Let $g: X \rightarrow S$ be a flat, proper morphism of
> reduced, complex analytic spaces. Fix a point $0 \in S$ and assume
> that $X_0$ is projective and has canonical singularities. Then every
> sequence of MMP-steps $X_0=X_0^0\dashrightarrow X_0^1\dashrightarrow
>  X_0^2 \dashrightarrow \cdots$ extends to a
> sequence of MMP-steps $$ X=X^0 \dashrightarrow X^1 \dashrightarrow X^2
>  \dashrightarrow \cdots, $$ over some open neighborhood $0 \in U
> \subset S$.

We consider the case of single MMP step and assume the step is a flip that is $X_0^0 \dashrightarrow X_0^1$ is a flip diagram and we want to extend it.

---

Before showing the proof we state 2 lemma used in the proof:

> **Lemma A** [Nak04, VI.3.8] Let $\pi: Y \rightarrow S$ be a projective,
> bimeromorphic morphism of analytic spaces, $Y$ smooth and $S$ normal.
> Let $D \subset Y$ be a smooth, nonexceptional divisor. Then the
> restriction map $\pi_* \omega_Y^m(m D) \rightarrow \pi_* \omega_D^m
>  \quad$ is surjective for $m \geq 1$.

and

> **Lemma B.** Let $\pi: X \rightarrow S$ be a proper morphism of normal,
> complex spaces. Let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$ and $W \subset S$ a
> Zariski closed subset. Assume that $\mathcal{O}_W
>  \otimes_S\left(\oplus_{r \geq 0} \pi_* L^r\right)$ is a finitely
> generated sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_W$-algebras.
>
> Then every compact subset $W^{\prime} \subset W$ has an open
> neighborhood $W^{\prime} \subset U \subset S$ such that $\mathcal{O}_U
>  \otimes_S\left(\oplus_{r \geq 0} \pi_* L^r\right)$ is a finitely
> generated sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_U$-algebras.

---

Let's show the proof of the **theorem 2** now:

**Proof.**

Step 1. We can prove that the contraction morphism $\phi_0:X_0\to Z_0$ extend to some $\phi:X\to Z$ (using some result on Kollár Mori Classification of three-dimensional flips 11.4)

Step 2. To show the existence of flip we require the finite generation of  $\oplus_{r\ge 0}\omega_Z^{[r]}$ or equivalently $\oplus_{r\ge 0} \omega_Z^{[r]}\left(r Z_0\right)$.

To do this we take resolution on $X$ with $\tau:Y\to X$ such that $g: Y\to X \to Z$ then by lemma A we have $$\oplus_{r \geq 0} g_* \omega_Y^r\left(r Y_0\right) \rightarrow \oplus_{r \geq 0}\left(g_0\right)_* \omega_{Y_0}^r \tag{**}$$ is surjective.

Since $X_0$ has canonical singularities $\tau_* \omega_{Y_0}^r=\omega_{X_0}^{[r]}$, and hence $g_* \omega_{Y_0}^r=\omega_{Z_0}^{[r]}$. We also have a natural inclusion $g_* \omega_Y^r\left(r Y_0\right) \hookrightarrow \omega_Z^{[r]}\left(r Z_0\right)$.

Thus pushing forward (**) we get a surjection
$$
\oplus_{r \geq 0} g_* \omega_Y^r\left(r Y_0\right) \rightarrow \oplus_{r \geq 0} \omega_Z^{[r]}\left(r Z_0\right) \rightarrow \oplus_{r \geq 0} \omega_{Z_0}^{[r]} .\tag{*}
$$

Note that $\oplus_{r \geq 0} \omega_{Z_0}^{[r]}$ is a finitely generated sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_{Z_0}$-algebras.

now apply the lemma B we have the finite generation of $\oplus_{r \geq 0} \omega_Z^{[r]}\left(r Z_0\right)$
.

---

**The question is about the final sentence of the proof:** why the Lemma B implies the finite generation of $\oplus_{r \geq 0} \omega_Z^{[r]}\left(r Z_0\right)$ and where do we use the surjectivity of (*)?